# Ajax button and render inside Primefaces datascroller?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org) `[<p:dataScroller />][2]` that I am using to display a list of lazy-loaded items.  My JSF code looks something like this:

```
<p:dataScroller id="scroller" value="#{myAction.myDataModel}" var="item" lazy="true" chunkSize="10">
  <section>
    <h3>Here is my item : <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" /></h3>
  </section>
</p:dataScroller>
```

This code works with no problem.  My backing code is able to lazy-load the items from the database on an as-needed basis, rather than pulling them all at once and paginating on the client side.  However, now I would like to add an `<h:commandLink />` within the datascroller and perform an Ajax submit, but only re-render the item that was clicked.  My backing action would update the state of my item and I would display a different message based on this state.  I thought I could do something like this:

```
<p:dataScroller id="scroller" value="#{myAction.myDataModel}" var="item" lazy="true" chunkSize="10">
  <section>
    <h:panelGroup id="#{item.name}" layout="block">
        <h3>Here is my item : <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" /></h3>
        <h:commandLink action="#{myAction.foo()}" value="Click here">
           <f:ajax render="#{item.name}" />
        </h:commandLink
    </h:panelGroup>
  </section>
</p:dataScroller>
```

...however, I've now learned that I can't have dynamic IDs within JSF, so the render of my `<h:panelGroup />` fails.  I can have the `render` attribute value of `<f:ajax />` set to my JSF form, but that re-renders everything from scratch, which is not the desired behavior.

If I have 100 items displayed in my `<p:dataScroller />` and I click on the link on item 30, is there any way to have only that item render?  Is there a better way to handle this use case?  Or am I completely stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dynamic id's. You can use [PrimeFaces selectors](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml), specifically designed for cases like this. So you can reference parents, items by class or whatever. The full [jquery selector api](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is at your disposal Very flexible! Just not sure if it works with h:commandButton and f:ajax (maybe h:commandButton and p:ajax works). But what works for sure is

```
<p:commandButton update="@(:parent)" value="update parent" />
```